# How to refer dynamicaly to an Excel cell with VBA Macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a loop through lines to read each time a cell, and write into another sheet.

```
Sub boucle_for()
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim lig As Integer
    Dim rr As Integer
    Dim cc As Integer

    col = 4
    lig = 3
    rr = 15
    cc = 24

    For i = 0 To 33
        Range("R[" & col & "]C[" & lig & "]").Formula = "=AVG('Weekly Changes'!R[" & rr & "]C[" & cc & "]:R[" & (rr + 1) & "]C[" & (cc + 1) & "])"
        rr = rr + 14
        lig = lig + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

My aim is to refer to a cell dynamically, but the VBA script says it's an error. I'm used to Java and JavaScript arrays, but I'm failing at this.

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer to use the Cells class (using the R1C1 reference) method, like this:

```
Cells(rr, col).Formula = ...
```

If you need a multi-cell range, you do something like this:

```
Range(Cells(rr, col), Cells(rx, colx)).Formula = ...
```

But you could also do this:

```
Range("A5").Formula = ...
```

Some people will make function to turn the column number into the letter. I think it's tacky, but it would look like this:

```
Range(MyNumberToLetterFunction(col) & rr).Formula = ...
```

or a mulit-cell range:

```
Range("A5:B6").Formula = ...
```

---

By the way, it's good practice to qualify your ranges using a sheet reference. It seems to work very well with loops, like you're doing:

```
Sheet1.Cells(rr, col).Value = ...
```

Or

```
Sheets("My Awesome Stuff").Cells(rr, col).Value = ...
```